# want to understand chrome console behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-console

when i am giving below string in chrome console cmd

`` 'x\x9c\xad\x96Ys\xda0\x10\x80\xff\ne\xfa`\xa7\x02\x03n\x93\x92\x19\x1e\x0c8\x1d\'\x10\x08Gj\x9e<\xb2-\x12\'\xbeb\xcb\xd3\x90L\xfe{%\xdb\x1c\x96e\x92\x1e/\x1c\xab\xd5\xb7\xab\xd5\x1ez\xad\xb7\xea\xe7\xb5\xd7\xba\x0f=D~\xd4??\x84^\x1d\xd4\xea\xeb \xf2\x12\x17R\xd1\xb0/\xdc(\xe0r:\x06\xd3\x996P\xc1`4\x99\xabb\xfd\x8dh\xb5\x8b{\xbd\xc0\xc7\xf7\x06\xf2m\x86\xe0\xac\x85tI\x10?\xf5\\x\'4\xda \xff/\x826\xb8V\xc8w\x8a\xeb\x14q\x1b\x04#>\x8d\xae\x1c\xc0\xb2\xbfE\x96\\d=a\x1ej\xef\xf1\x89\xe0Cg\xfd\x82\xa2@\xd8{\xdb\xeb\xc9\x84\xd9\x12\xbf\x1c\x8aN\xcb\xa2nY\xd4\xee\xa4\xb2\xdc\x99\xafEgP\x12\xc9\xf1i,\xe8\xba.2\x1e\xb5[\xad\x13\x81D|0\xb8\x05\x83\xd9\xed\xfc\xa72\x1d\x8f\xaf\x16@]\xce\x00Q\x07`\xb60....(long string) ``

it giving me below result in some binary format. i want to understand what exactly happening behind the scenes, same thing i would like to apply in my code.

````
eú`§n8'Gj<²-'¾bËÓLþ{%Ûe/«Õ·«Õz­·êçµ×º=D~Ô??^Ôêë òRÑ°/Ü(àr:Ó6PÁ`4«býhµ{½ÀÇ÷òmà¬tI?õ\x'4Ú ÿ/6¸VÈwëq#>®À²¿E\d=ajïñàCgý¢@Ø{ÛëÉÙ¿NË¢nYÔî¤²Ü¯EgPÉñi,èº.2µ[­D|0¸Ùíü§2¯@]Î```
````

Comment: `'\x41'` is the letter `'A'` ... so `'\x41\x42\x43'` is `'ABC'` ... it's hexadecimal notation

Comment: I tried  hexa converter but no lock.